# how to check foreach index is integer or string in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

how to check foreach index is integer or string in smarty?

```
<?php
$arr = array(9 => 'Tennis', 3 => 'Swimming', 8 => 'Coding');
$smarty->assign('myArray', $arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post an example on why you need to know that?

In general, you can use the PHP functions `is_string` and `is_integer` to detect types.

Also use `{php}{/php}` to use PHP code inside the Smarty templates.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was useful to you, that would be great if you could mark it as "accepted". Thanks!